# Omit last line in nested for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I have a nested for loop:

`for i in range(0,6):
    for j in range(0,10):
        print(j, end="")
    print("\n",0)`

Which results in the following:

`0123456789
 0
0123456789
 0
0123456789
 0
0123456789
 0
0123456789
 0
0123456789
 0`

How do I omit the last `0` from the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply add an if as follows:

```
for i in range(0, 6):
    for j in range(0, 10):
        print(j, end="")
    if i != 5:
        print("\n", 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can keep a variable to see if the process is complete and there is no need for more zeroes.

```
done = False
for i in range(0,6):
    for j in range(0,10):
        print(j, end="")
        if i == 5 and j == 9:
            done = True
    if not done:
        print("\n",0)

    # You can also use this variable to break the loop
    # after the process is complete.
```